# Наложить картинку на картинку в пределах блока

Tags: css

надо срочно поставить картинку на картинку. знаю что ставится абсолютом , но вот проблема такая , что из за этого сам wrap уезжает на верх экрана , а надо , чтобы  этот блок не улетал наверх экрана. Надо , чтобы картинки наложились , но внутри блока и нечего не куда не улетало бы.

```css
.wrap img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.wrap {
  img:last-child {
      &:hover {
        opacity: 0;
      }
  }

  }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img class="sea" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/demo/img/image1.jpeg?tr=w-400,h-300" alt="" style="">
  <img class="logo" src="http://notwebsafe.com/presos/web-hipster/images/CSS3_Logo.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <img class="sea" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/demo/img/image1.jpeg?tr=w-400,h-300" alt="" style="">
  <img class="logo" src="http://notwebsafe.com/presos/web-hipster/images/CSS3_Logo.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <img class="sea" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/demo/img/image1.jpeg?tr=w-400,h-300" alt="" style="">
  <img class="logo" src="http://notwebsafe.com/presos/web-hipster/images/CSS3_Logo.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <img class="sea" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/demo/img/image1.jpeg?tr=w-400,h-300" alt="" style="">
  <img class="logo" src="http://notwebsafe.com/presos/web-hipster/images/CSS3_Logo.png" alt="">
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <img class="sea" src="https://ik.imagekit.io/demo/img/image1.jpeg?tr=w-400,h-300" alt="" style="">
  <img class="logo" src="http://notwebsafe.com/presos/web-hipster/images/CSS3_Logo.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первую картинку оставить как есть, вторую сделать абсолютно спозиционированной. wrap'у поставить `position:relative;`.

Answer (score 1):

Ты можешь одну из картинок поставить в background, а для второй указать ширину и высоту идентичные твоему блоку, судя по коду который ты отправил в этом блоке только картинки и будут

Comment: <style>.wrap{ background: url("твой адрес");}</style> <div class="wrap"><img src="второй адрес" width="100%" height="100%">

Comment: вроде как-то так, только приведи код в порядок и для свойства background укажи нормально параметры вроде no-repeat и т.д., если это стало твоим решение - дай знать

Comment: дело такое , что мне надо при наведении , чтобы одна картинка пропадала. Картинки будут выгружаться из базы данных при помощи php

Answer (score 1):

Можно несколько изображений добавить в `background-image`, последнее изображения в списке будет в самом нижнем слое:

```css
.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:600px;
  height:175px;
  background:
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/101/110/110) no-repeat 0 0,
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/102/120/120) no-repeat 50% 50%,
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/103/100/100) no-repeat 100% 100%,
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/100/600/175) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

.wrap:hover {
  background:
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/102/120/120) no-repeat 50% 50%,
    url(https://picsum.photos/id/100/600/175) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"></div>
```

Comment: дело такое , что мне надо при наведении , чтобы одна картинка пропадала. Картинки будут выгружаться из базы данных при помощи php

Comment: @XXXXXX особых проблем нет, сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: буду ждать ответа

Comment: @XXXXXX я его уже 5 минут как поменял

Comment: не обновлялось , простите , посмотрите , пожалуйста , я обновил вопрос . Вы просто кажись меня не правильно поняли. Я сильно извиняюсь

Comment: @XXXXXX я по прежнему не понимаю что я не угадал =)

Comment: ну есть три блока врап. внутри их есть картинки соц сетей . фэйсбук, твиттер и тд , и при наводе , я должен сменить картинку на другой цвет (в моем случае поменять эту картинку на другую ) Я накладываю их друг на друга и вывожу нужную при наводе

Comment: @XXXXXX честно,  не понимаю Вас

Comment: 10 картинок в общем. 5 простых и 5 ховер версии =5 блоков . Наводишь на простую , появляется ховер версия.

Comment: Псевдокласс `:hover` c меняющимся бекграундом, не?

Comment: @РашенБеар так то он есть в ответе =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ автор просто пытается писать костыли вместо банальных вещей

Comment: АВТОР, это крайне устаревший подход, absolute лучше вообще не пользоваться, есть flex и grid для таких целей

Comment: @DaniilPetrenko спору нет, но вопрос не про это =)